# XMLEncode function in C#

Tags: c#, vbscript

I have got below XMLEncode function in VBScript function. I want to write similar function in C# 2.0

```
Function XMLEncode(byVal stringtoencode)
    Dim strTemp ' As String
    strTemp = stringtoencode
    strTemp = Replace( strTemp, chr(38), "&amp;" )
    strTemp = Replace( strTemp, chr(34), "&quot;" )
    strTemp = Replace( strTemp, chr(60), "&lt;" )
    strTemp = Replace( strTemp, chr(62), "&gt;" )
    strTemp = Replace( strTemp, chr(169), "&copy;" )
    XMLEncode = strTemp
End Function
```

Please suggest!! if there is any in built function in c# or do I need to write same logic in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string xml = "<node>it's my \"node\" & i like it<node>";
using (XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(@"c:\xmlTest.xml", Encoding.Unicode))
{
    xtw.WriteStartElement("xmlEncodeTest");
    xtw.WriteAttributeString("testAttribute", xml);
    xtw.WriteString(xml);
    xtw.WriteEndElement();
}

// RESULT:
/*
<xmlEncodeTest testAttribute="&lt;node&gt;it's my &quot;node&quot; &amp; i like it&lt;node&gt;">
    &lt;node&gt;it's my "node" &amp; i like it&lt;node&gt;
</xmlEncodeTest>
*/
```

From [This site](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx)

Comment: What is this BigMike, I am looking for a function!! I am using .NET 2.0

Comment: follow the link, there're are 4 ways to achieve XML Escaping. From the simple way (escaping chars manually via string replaces), to the complex solution (using the XmlTextWriter), passing through some encoding utilis.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode-Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/w3te6wfz.aspx), maybe this can solve your problem.